# Calculate outliers of a group of specific columns then identify ids which have >5 columns with outliers

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, subset, outliers

I'm working with a big dataframe (df). I would like to calculate outliers for a specific subset of columns based off the mean + 3 sd.

I first extracted the columns I wanted, so all the columns with color in their column names.

```
colors = colnames(df)[grep('color', colnames(df))]
```

I'm not sure how I should then go about looping it to calculate the outliers across all the columns using this new variable. The formula I had was:

```
# id those with upper outliers
uthr = mean(df$color)+3*sd(df$color)
rm_u_ids = df$id[which(df$color >= uthr)]

# id those with lower outliers
lthr = mean(df$color)-3*sd(df$color)
rm_l_ids = df$id[which(df$color <= lthr)]

# remove those with both upper and lower outliers
rm_ids = sort(c(rm_u_ids, rm_l_ids))
df_2 = df %>% filter(!id %in% rm_ids)
```

Now, the actual problem. 
I would like to use something similar to do the following:
1) for each color in `colors`, identify those id's with outliers, maybe save this info elsewhere,
2) using that info (maybe in a list or separate data frame), identify the id's which appeared in 5 columns or more, or `colors`,
3) subset the original data frame with this list so we eliminate those id's with outliers in 5 color columns or more.

Does that make sense? I'm not sure if a loop is also recommended for this problem.

Thank you and sorry if I made it sound more complex than it should be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function which returns the `id`'s of outliers

```
find_outlier <- function(df, x) {
  uthr = mean(x)+3*sd(x)
  rm_u_ids = df$id[which(x >= uthr)]
  # id those with lower outliers
  lthr = mean(x)-3*sd(x)
  rm_l_ids = df$id[which(x <= lthr)]
  # remove those with both upper and lower outliers
  unique(sort(c(rm_u_ids, rm_l_ids)))
}
```

Apply it to every `colors` column, calculate their count with `table` and remove the `id`'s which occur more than 5 times.

```
all_ids <- lapply(df[colors], find_outlier, df = df)

temp_tab <- table(unlist(all_ids))
remove_ids <- names(temp_tab[temp_tab >= 5])
subset(df, !id %in% remove_ids)
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah, thanks for your solution. I tried using this and it broke at the 'lapply' function because 'colors' are characters. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Erika Oops...sorry, it should be `df[colors]` in `lapply`. I have updated the answer. Can you check now?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the clever answers already provided is to convert the relevant columns into a matrix and use some fast matrix operations:

```
df = iris
colors = colnames(iris)[1:4]
m = as.matrix(df[,colors])

# Standardize the numeric values in each column
m = scale(m)

# Apply some outlier definition rules, e.g.
# detect measurements with |Zscore|>3
outliers = abs(m)>3
# detect rows with at least 5 such measurements
outliers = rowSums(outliers)
which(outliers>=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your `data.frame` only has the numeric variables you want

```
findOutlierCols = function(color.df){
  hasOutliers = function(col){
    bds = mean(col) + c(-3,3)*sd(col)
    if(any(col <= bds[1]) || any(col >= bds[2])){
      return(TRUE)
    }else{
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }  
  apply(color.df, 2, hasOutliers)
}

## make some fake data
set.seed(123)
x = matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10)
color.df = data.frame(x)
colnames(x) = paste0("color.", colors()[1:10])
color.df = apply(color.df, 2, function(col){col+rbinom(100, 5, 0.1)})

boxplot(color.df)
findOutlierCols(color.df)
```

[image]

```
> findOutlierCols(color.df)
   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```